# Quando e como implementar o Parcelable vs Serializable?

Tags: java, android, orientação-a-objetos, classes, interface

Após muito tempo utilizando a implementação Serializable nas minhas classes na plataforma Java(Android), descobri o Parcelable, mas fiquei na dúvida em relação as seguintes questões abaixo:

**1. Quando utilizar (escolher entre) o Parcelable vs Serializable?**
 **2. Como implementar o Parcelable e Serializable?**
 **3. Quais são as diferenças de performance das duas implementações?**

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Vamos lá:

*1. Quando utilizar (escolher entre) o Parcelable vs Serializable?*

Usar Serializable é mais fácil e mais rápido de ser implementado. Entretanto, a performance é pior.
Usar Parcelable gasta um pouco mais de tempo para implementar e é um pouco mais complexo que o Serializable. Apesar disso, usar Parcelable tem uma performance melhor.

*2. Como implementar o Parcelable e Serializable?*

Abaixo, segue um exemplo de uma classe que implementa o Parcelable.

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class Cliente implements Parcelable {
 private int codigo;
 private String nome;

 public Cliente(int codigo, String nome) {
   this.codigo = codigo;
   this.nome = nome;
 }

 private Cliente(Parcel p){
   codigo = from.readInt();
   nome = from.readString();
 }

 public static final Parcelable.Creator<Cliente>
   CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Cliente>() {

   public Cliente createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
     return new Cliente(in);
   }

   public Cliente[] newArray(int size) {
     return new Cliente[size];
   }
 };

 public int getCodigo() {
   return codigo;
 }

 public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
   this.codigo = codigo;
 }

 public String getNome() {
   return nome;
 }

 public void setNome(String nome) {
   this.nome = nome;
 }

 @Override
 public int describeContents() {
   return 0;
 }

 @Override
 public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
   dest.writeInt(codigo);
   dest.writeString(nome); 
 }
}
```

No exemplo, foi necessário reescrever dois métodos: `describeContents` e `writeToParcel`. O primeiro é um inteiro que identifica a classe. Já o segundo é responsável por serializar as informações da classe.
Uma outra coisa importante é o atributo estático CREATOR. Todas as classes que implementarem o Parcelable, devem ter esse atributo, uma vez que, ele é quem junta as funcionalidades de um DataInputStream e DataOutputStream para serializar e deserializar objetos. Observe ainda que ela chama o construtor privado de Cliente que recebe um Parcel que nos permite ler dados dele e passando para os atributos.

Passando os dados via Intent:

```
Cliente cliente = new Cliente(1, "Glauber");
Intent it = new Intent(this, Teste2Activity.class);
it.putExtra("cliente", cliente);
startActivity(it);
```

Para ler os dados, é bem simples:

```
Cliente c =  getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("cliente");
```

---

Agora, usaremos o Serializable:

Vamos usar um exemplo parecido com o que usamos no Parcelable:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
public class Pessoa implements Serializable{

    private int codigo;
    private String nome;
    public static final long  serialVersionUID = 100L;

    public int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }
    public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
}
```

Fazendo assim, você consegue passar objetos da classe Pessoa para outras activities, podendo até adicioná-los a listas.
Veja:

```
ArrayList<Pessoa> pessoas = new ArrayList<Pessoa>();
pessoas.add(new Pessoa(1, "Glauber"));
pessoas.add(new Pessoa(2, "Nelson"));

Intent it = new Intent(this, Tela2Activity.class);
// Caso queira passar a lista toda use
it.putExtra("pessoas", pessoas); 
// Caso queira passar apenas um objeto
it.putExtra("pessoa", pessoas.get(0)); 
startActivity(it);
```

E agora, vamos recuperar o que passamos anteriormente:

```
Pessoa pessoa = (Pessoa) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("pessoa");

ArrayList<Pessoa> pessoas = (ArrayList<Pessoa>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("pessoas");

System.out.println("Pessoa: "+ pessoa.getNome());
System.out.println("Pessoas: "+ pessoas.get(0).getNome());
```

*3. Quais são as diferenças em relação a performance das duas implementações?*

O Parcelable é mais eficiente do que o Serializable em tempo de execução.
Abaixo seguem resultados dos testes feitos:

Metodologia usada nos testes:

- Imitar o processo de passagem de objeto a uma atividade, colocando um objeto em um pacote e chamando Bundle # writeToParcel (Parcel, int) e, em seguida, buscar-lo de volta;
- Executar isso em um loop 1000 vezes;
- Os objetos testados são o `SerializableDeveloper` e o `ParcelableDeveloper` (vide link de referência do teste)
- Dispositivos testados: 
  LG Nexus 4 / Android 4.2.2;
  Samsung Nexus 10 / Android 4.2.2;
  HTC Desire Z / 2.3.3.

Resultados:
[image: Resultados do teste.]

Nexus 10
Serializable: 1.0004ms –  Parcelable: 0.0850ms –- Parcelable 10.16x melhor.

Nexus 4
Serializable: 1.8539ms – Parcelable: 0.1824ms –- Parcelable 11.80x melhor.

Desire Z
Serializable: 5.1224ms – Parcelable: 0.2938ms –- Parcelable 17.36x melhor.

**Conclusão:**

- Parcelable é mais rápido
- Parcelable leva um tempo a mais para implementar
- Serializable é mais fácil de implementar

**Referências:**

[Implementação de Parcelable e Serializable](http://nglauber.blogspot.com.br/2010/01/android-passando-objetos-em-intents.html)

[Teste de Eficiência](http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/)

[Documentação Oficial - Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)

[Documentação Oficial - Serializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html)

[Postagem interessante no StackOverFlow - (en)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323074/android-difference-between-parcelable-and-serializable)

[Qual a finalidade da interface Serializable?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88270/)

Comment: +1 na sua resposta, muito boa^^

Comment: Outra vantagem do Serializable é que ele pode ser usado para persistência de dados em arquivo, ao contrário do Parcelable. Porém com a ressalva de que de uma versão do Java para outra o mecanismo de serialização pode mudar, e aí seus objetos serializados serão perdidos. É útil porém como cache temporário.

Comment: Os números assustam mas, a não ser que você vá passar uma quantidade enorme de elementos num Bundle, você não vai notar diferença entre os dois. Usar Parcelable em tudo é otimização prematura.