# Passar objeto por parâmetro causa erro - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-activity, intent

Estou tentando passar um objeto por parâmetro, mas ocorre um erro na linha "it.putExtra("tag", obj);":

> Cannot resolve method (java.lang.String, meu pacote.minhaClasse)

Segue o codigo

```
Obj obj = new Obj();
Intent it;
it = new Intent(this, MinhaClasse.class);
it.putExtra("tag", obj);
startActivity(it);
```

Outra pergunta, como recuperar esse objeto na outra Activity?

Comment: Olá, essa resposta poderá te ajudar http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/70421/como-passar-informacoes-da-listview-para-uma-nova-activity/70456#70456

Comment: Essa pergunta pode ser bem útil para você, Vitor: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38492

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para que você passe um objeto como parametro é necessário que o mesmo seja Serializado, ou seja, implemente `Serializable`. 
Segue um simples exemplo: 

Classe:

```
public class Params implements Serializable{
    public String param1="";
    public String param2="";
    public String param3="";
}
```

Setando o parametro:

```
 Params obj = new Params();
        obj.param1 = "Parametro UM ";
        obj.param2 = "Parametro DOIS ";
        obj.param3 = "Parametro TRES ";
        Intent it;
        it = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        it.putExtra("Param", obj);
```

Saudações

Comment: Uma outra maneira seria utilizando `Parcelable`