# Por que serializar objeto para enviar em outra Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Qual a explicação para serializar o objeto tanto usando a implementação `serializable` ou `Parcelable`. Eu sei que isso serve para criar uma nova instancia do objeto na outra atividade, mas por que "não posso" usar a mesma instancia dele na outra atividade?

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38492/4808

Answer (score 6, accepted):

De acordo com [esta questão no SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705419/why-objects-must-be-serialized-before-being-passed-to-activities-in-android) é preciso serializar objetos porque eles são passados a uma classe chamada `ActivityManagerNative` que fica em um processo separado dos demais aplicativos.

Quando dois processos distintos querem se comunicar a memória não é compartilhada e portanto não é possível passar de um para o outro o mesmo objeto.

Porém a resposta não entra no mérito de por que a comunicação foi projetada para funcionar assim.

A explicação mais provável é que o mecanismo de comunicação por `Intent`'s do Android foi projetado para funcionar tanto entre componentes (`Activities`, `Services`, etc.) de um mesmo processo (aplicativo) como entre componentes de processos diferentes (de uma `Activity` do aplicativo A para a `Activity` do aplicativo B, por exemplo).

Ou seja, a serialização é necessária para permitir a transferência de dados via `IPC` (Comunicação entre processos).

Entre duas `Activities` de um mesmo processo é possível se comunicar sem serializar o objeto, basta não usar o mecanismo de `Intents` e em lugar disso usar um recurso compartilhado (um objeto estático global ou herdado por ambas as `Activities`, ou ainda um *Singleton*).