# Qual a finalidade da interface Serializable?

Tags: java, interface, serialização, desserialização

Exemplo de implementação:

```
 public class MyClass implements Serializable{
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 }
```

Comment: https://camilolopes.wordpress.com/2008/06/04/serializacao-em-java/

Answer (score 55, accepted):

A serialização significa salvar o estado atual dos objetos em arquivos em formato binário para o seu computador, sendo assim esse estado poderá ser recuperado posteriormente recriando o objeto em memória assim como ele estava no momento da sua serialização.

Veja a ilustração:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte: [State of the art - Nuances sobre serialização de objetos com herança em Java](http://luizricardo.org/2014/10/nuances-sobre-serializacao-de-objetos-com-heranca-em-java/)

Para que seja possível serializar e desserializar um objeto, é obrigatório que a sua classe implemente a interface `Serializable`.

Um exemplo de um código que serializa um objeto:

```
import java.io.*;

public class SerializeDemo
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      Employee e = new Employee();
      e.name = "Reyan Ali";
      e.address = "Phokka Kuan, Ambehta Peer";
      e.SSN = 11122333;
      e.number = 101;

      try
      {
         FileOutputStream fileOut =
         new FileOutputStream("/tmp/employee.ser");
         ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
         out.writeObject(e);
         out.close();
         fileOut.close();
         System.out.printf("Serialized data is saved in /tmp/employee.ser");
      }catch(IOException i)
      {
          i.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Desserializando o mesmo objeto:

```
import java.io.*;
public class DeserializeDemo
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      Employee e = null;
      try
      {
         FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("/tmp/employee.ser");
         ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
         e = (Employee) in.readObject();
         in.close();
         fileIn.close();
      }catch(IOException i)
      {
         i.printStackTrace();
         return;
      }catch(ClassNotFoundException c)
      {
         System.out.println("Employee class not found");
         c.printStackTrace();
         return;
      }
      System.out.println("Deserialized Employee...");
      System.out.println("Name: " + e.name);
      System.out.println("Address: " + e.address);
      System.out.println("SSN: " + e.SSN);
      System.out.println("Number: " + e.number);
    }
}
```

Resultado:

> Deserialized Employee...
>   Name: Reyan Ali
>   Address:Phokka Kuan, Ambehta Peer
>   SSN: 0
>   Number:101

Fonte: [Tutorials Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm)

Comment: Vim aqui dar +1 só pela foto do bicho inflável.

Comment: Que não é muito precisa, por sinal. O bicho deveria ser desmontado em suas partes componentes, que deveriam passar através de um duto, para ser remontado do outro lado. :P

Comment: É legal citar por exemplo que para colocar objetos em fila, clonar (apache commons) é preciso implementar a interface Serializable

Comment: `Para que seja possível serializar e desserializar um objeto, é obrigatório que a sua classe implemente a interface Serializable.` NÃO é obrigatorio.

Comment: @DavidSchrammel poderia me mostrar como serializar uma classe que não implementa a interface Serializable? Eu fui em busca de uma fonte para corroborar minha afirmação e no último link da minha resposta tem esse texto: _"The class must implement the java.io.Serializable interface."_ Não compreendo o que você está afirmando.

Comment: O pior é que no fundo a imagem é ao contrário. A versão serializada frequentemente é mais inflada que a versão da memória :) Mas entendi a intenção.

Comment: @bigown heheh.. bom, a intenção é justamente dizer que o objeto fica em um estado que serve para ser guardado, e não para ser usado. Nunca cheguei a verificar o tamanho de um objeto em memória para saber o tamanho dele, mas a intenção é essa aí ;) ainda bem que entendeu

Comment: @Math Talvez ele esteja usando o termo "serializar" de uma forma mais genérica, por exemplo quando você transforma um objeto em string JSON, que também é uma forma de serialização, embora não use o mecanismo fornecido pelo Java. Usando-se o mecanismo do Java não apenas a classe deve implementar `Serializable`, como você disse, como também as classes de todos os seus atributos, e os atributos dos seus atributos e assim por diante.

Comment: @Math existem muitas maneiras de serializar um objeto, particularmente eu utilizo uma solução que consiste em serializar uma instancia de um objeto em um json e recuperar a instancia utilizando reflection; mas isso pode ser implementado na mão.

Answer (score 15):

Ela dá capacidade da classe produzir um formato em que os dados do objeto sejam usados de forma externa ao código, em geral ele é persistido em alguma forma de armazenamento temporário ou permanente ou é transmitido para outro recurso.

Este formato pode ser texto ou binário em diversas variantes padrões ou proprietárias. É muito comum usar JSON ou XML.

A desserialização é o processo oposto. Pega-se dados em um formato conhecido e coloca os dados encontrados no estado serializado dentro dos membros da classe criando ou atualizando um objeto.

Implementar esta interface não é muito trivial, ainda que pareça ser. É comum se usar uma solução pronta que usa reflexão. É comum a serialização expor partes privadas da classe, o que muitas vezes não é desejável, então precisa de cuidado, por outro lado sem as partes privadas pode não ter tudo o que é necessário.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: json , xml também?

Comment: Estes são os formatos mais comuns quando se serializa para texto.

Comment: blz obrigado pelo retorno :)

Answer (score 8):

Adicionando a interface serializable será possível transformar o objeto num formato que poderá ser salvo num arquivo. Por exemplo, para utilizar um ObjectOutputStream e salvar um objeto num arquivo do disco será necessário implementar essa interface.