# Por que a interface Serializable é vazia no código-fonte do JDK?

Tags: java, design-pattern, interface, serialização

Eu sei o que é serialização e qual é o uso dela. Também sei quando não utilizá-la. Já li o item 74 do Effetive Java. Minha pergunta é, qual a finalidade de uma interface vazia, na qual não há nada a ser implementado?

```
package java.io;
public interface Serializable {
}
```

Seria apenas como uma espécie de marcação? Se sim, em que momento as classes "marcadas" como serializáveis seriam utilizadas? E qual seria o nome dessa estratégia de marcação?

Comment: Relacionada(ou duplicata): [Qual a finalidade da interface Serializable?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/88275/28595)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger, o que é "identificar a semântica do que está sendo serializado"?

Comment: Eu reabri porque a pergunta que foi marcada como duplicata não tem a informação perguntada aqui, procurei bastante, perguntei para outras pessoas e fala sobre a `Serializable`, não porque ela é vazia. Ela é só relacionada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não saberia dizer porque optaram fazer isso, talvez nem eles mais saibam e questionem a decisão, mas sua suposição é a mais óbvia explicação. Ela tem nome, chama-se [*marker interface*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76511/101) e ela serve apenas para informar que certas classes podem fazer algo, mas a implementação disto não está na classe. Quase sempre é um erro e tem opção melhor.

Particularmente eu prefiro uma anotação de atributo personalizado, algo como `@Serializable`. qualquer ferramenta de código ou externa pode "olhar" para a classe e saber que ela pode ou não fazer algo, é só usar a criatividade. E justamente por ela mostrar que tem uma capacidade e não ter a capacidade dentro dela não deveria ser uma interface.

Comment: Imagino que se trate de uma interface porque é anterior ao Java 1.5 quando a linguagem passou a ter as _Annotations_.